# Not allowed to return a result set from a trigger

Tags: mysql

I create a trigger and i didn't set any return value but there is showing a error that

```
    DELIMITER //
    CREATE TRIGGER Trig_InsertIBDActionURL  AFTER INSERT ON tbl_ibdcalllog FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
      DECLARE ActionURL varchar(500);
       select @ActionURL := trim(`actionurl`) from tbl_client where id=NEW.clientid;
         if(CHAR_LENGTH(ActionURL) <> 0) THEN
                    insert into tbl_ibdactionurl (Call_id,clientid,mobile_number,language,call_starttime,call_duration,keypress,file_name,obd_status,
    operator,circle,failure_reason,smsflag,datacapture,latch_duration,latchcreditused,creditused,country_code,callcenter_no,ActionURL)
            (select id,clientid,mobile_number,language,call_starttime,call_duration,keypress,file_name,obd_status,operator,circle,failure_reason,
    smsflag,datacapture,latch_duration,latchcreditused,creditused,country_code,callcenter_no, @ActionURL from tbl_ibdcalllog where id = NEW.id);
          END IF;
    END;//

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your `insert into .. select from` is the culprit here. Change it like below by removing the `()` around the `SELECT` statement (which probably giving a sense that you are trying to return a result set) and see if it goes off

```
insert into tbl_ibdactionurl  
(Call_id,clientid,mobile_number,language,call_starttime,
 call_duration,keypress,file_name,obd_status,   
operator,circle,failure_reason,smsflag,datacapture,latch_duration,
latchcreditused,creditused,country_code,callcenter_no,ActionURL)
select id,clientid,mobile_number,language,call_starttime,call_duration,
keypress,file_name,obd_status,operator,circle,failure_reason,   
smsflag,datacapture,latch_duration,latchcreditused,creditused,
country_code,callcenter_no, @ActionURL 
from tbl_ibdcalllog 
where id = NEW.id;
```